# How to Merge SQL Query(Help required)

Tags: sql-server

Dear friends, below are my two SQL queries:

```
select distinct  
    a_bm.DestProvider_ID,
    a_bm.DestCircel_ID,
    convert(datetime,dbo.fnToDate(a_bm.BM_BillFrom),103) as fromdate,
    convert(datetime,dbo.fnToDate(a_bm.BM_BillTo),103) as todate,
    t_rec.TapInRec as BillRecevable,
    t_rec.TapInRec as Billreceied
from Auditdata_BillingMaster a_bm 
inner join TapInRecordMaster t_rec
    on a_bm.DestProvider_ID = t_rec.DestProviderMaster_ID
    and a_bm.DestCircel_ID = t_rec.DestCircelMaster_ID
    and convert(datetime,dbo.fnToDate(a_bm.BM_BillFrom),103)> =  
        convert(datetime,t_rec.Months) 
    and convert(datetime,dbo.fnToDate(a_bm.BM_BillTo),103)<= 
        convert(datetime,t_rec.BillTo)
where a_bm.DestProvider_ID=4
and a_bm.DestCircel_ID=22
and a_bm.typeoffile=1
and convert(datetime,dbo.fnToDate(a_bm.BM_BillFrom),103)>=
    convert(datetime,'6/1/2009') 
and convert(datetime,dbo.fnToDate(a_bm.BM_BillFrom),103)<=
    convert(datetime,'7/30/2009')
```

```
select Temp_tbl.fromdate from Temp_tbl Temp_tbl
inner join (
    select
        convert(datetime,dbo.fnToDate(BM_BillFrom),103) as a1,
        convert(datetime,dbo.fnToDate(BM_BillTo),103) as b1,
        count(*) as c1,
        am_bm.DestProvider_ID,
        am_bm.DestCircel_ID
    from Auditdata_BillingMaster am_bm
    inner join Temp_tbl tmp
        on tmp.Provider_ID=am_bm.DestProvider_ID
        and tmp.Circel_ID=am_bm.DestCircel_ID
    where  convert(datetime,tmp.fromdate)>=
        convert(datetime,dbo.fnToDate(am_bm.BM_BillFrom),103)
    and convert(datetime,tmp.todate) <= 
        convert(datetime,dbo.fnToDate(am_bm.BM_BillTo),103)
    group by
        convert(datetime,dbo.fnToDate(BM_BillFrom),103),
        convert(datetime,dbo.fnToDate(BM_BillTo),103),
        am_bm.DestProvider_ID,
        am_bm.DestCircel_ID
    ) b
    on Temp_tbl.Provider_ID = b.DestProvider_ID
    and Temp_tbl.Circel_ID = b.DestCircel_ID
    and convert(datetime,Temp_tbl.fromdate,101)>= convert(datetime,(b.a1),101)
    and convert(datetime,Temp_tbl.todate) <= convert(datetime,(b.b1),101)
```

I want to merge above 2 SQL query in SQL Server 2000.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Right, hopefully that's easier to read, but I doubt it :-)

Comment: Merge them to...do...what, exactly?

Comment: Show us the table structures (best: database diagram) for these tables involved (Auditdata_BillingMaster, TapInRecordMaster, temp_tbl)! What do you want to achieve, select?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean to JOIN or UNION both tables?

If you mean to JOIN both query results, simply take both results as input for JOIN statement.

How you join both results is really dependent on your database design. Preferably the join is based on referential integrity enforcing the relationship between the results to ensure data integrity. But since you do not mention the join condition, let me assume you will join based on DestProvider_ID  & DestCircel_ID.

```
select 
    result1.DestProvider_ID,
    result1.DestCircel_ID,
    result1.fromdate,
    result1.todate,
    result1.BillRecevable,
    result1.Billreceied,
    result2.fromdate
from 
    ( *your first query* ) as result1
inner join
    (select
        Temp_tbl.fromdate, 
        am_bm.DestProvider_ID, 
        am_bm.DestCircel_ID
    from Temp_tbl Temp_tbl

        *the rest of your second query*

    ) as result2 on result1.DestProvider_ID = result2.DestProvider_ID 
                 and result1.DestCircel_ID = result2.DestCircel_ID
```

UNION:

If you want to take multiple select statements and combine them into one result set, UNION statement is the easiest way to go:

```
SELECT column1a, column2a, column3a FROM tableA
UNION
SELECT column1b, column2b, column3b FROM tableB
```

This is possible only if:

- both queries have same number of columns
- Corresponding columns in each query expression must be of the same data type
- data type of column1a == column1b
- data type of column2a == column2b
- data type of column3a == column3b

Since both of your queries do not have same number of columns, you can't merge them, at least with UNION select.

Comment: The number of columns and data type formats don't match, you need to rewrite that query to make it work using a UNION as the easiest way to combine the two queries.

Comment: Just giving an example of what kind of statements that could be merged with UNION. At the end, I mentioned that both queries could not be merged.

Comment: Questioner may mean combine in terms of a cartesian product rather than a simple union. In fact, I hope they mean that since, as you point out, there's no other way to do it as the queries stand at the moment.